# Adding new data and new column on a pandas dataframe with zero filled

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Can any one tell me a way to add a new column and data to an existing dataframe , similar to that shown below. When i enter a new column Name and value , it should add a column with new value at the last and zeroes in all other places, as shown below in pandas dataframe

**DataFrame :**

```
A  B  C 
1  2  3
4  5  6
```

Enter New Column Name: `D`

Enter New Value: `7`

**New DataFrame**

```
A  B  C  D
1  2  3  0
4  5  6  0
0  0  0  7
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create the append df with `concat`

```
out = pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame({'D':[7]})]).fillna(0)
out
     A    B    C    D
0  1.0  2.0  3.0  0.0
1  4.0  5.0  6.0  0.0
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  7.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Other solution, with [`.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html#pandas-dataframe-append):

```py
print(df.append({"D": 7}, ignore_index=True).fillna(0).astype(int))
```

Prints:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  0
1  4  5  6  0
2  0  0  0  7
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`.fillna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
df.loc[df.shape[0], 'D'] = 7
df = df.fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

Result:

```
print(df)

   A  B  C  D
0  1  2  3  0
1  4  5  6  0
2  0  0  0  7
```